# How to use file.seperator in ibatis resource attribute of sql-map tag

Tags: java, ibatis

I am using ibatis for OR mapping of my application. me and my team is working on two different operating systems, systems are UBUNTU and Windows xp. I have a `sqlmapconfig.xml` file in which I refer my ibatis query xml file, in which I write all the queries.

But when I create sqlmapconfig I want to give a path of my query.xml in resource attribute  of sql-map tag by using file separator so it can adjust the separator by operating system, for that I have written code like below in sqlmapconfig.xml

```
<sqlMap 
      resource="file:com${file.separator}platysgroup${file.separator}lmexserver${file.separator}mobile${file.separator}dao${file.separator}ibatis{file.separator}lmexusermobileinfo.xml" />
```

but when I run my application I get an exception:

> com.ibatis.common.xml.NodeletException: Error parsing XML.  Cause: java.lang.RuntimeException: Error parsing XPath '/sqlMapConfig/sqlMap'.  Cause: java.io.IOException: Could not find resource file:comfile.separatorplatysgroupfile.separatorlmexserverfile.separatormobilefile.separatordaofile.separatoribatis{file.separator}lmexusermobileinfo.xml`

How to resolve this? Please help me.

Thank you

Comment: sorry for not writting a code i miss it completely. my sqlmapconfig.xml code is:  <sqlMap
  resource="file:com${file.separator}platysgroup${file.separator}lmexserver${file.separator}mobile${file.separator}dao${file.separator}ibatis{file.separator}lmexusermobileinfo.xml" />

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Error "**com.ibatis.common.xml.NodeletException: Error parsing XML. Cause: java.lang.RuntimeException: Error parsing XPath '/sqlMapConfig/sqlMap'. Cause: java.io.IOException: Could not find resource file:comfile.separatorplatysgroupfile.separatorlmexserverfile.separatormobilefile.separatordaofile.separatoribatis{file.separator}lmexusermobileinfo.xml** indicates that the requested sqlMapConfig.xml is not placed properly,Place it in the `src` folder. and check if your are able to access it.

Comment: i come across the same problem with my app-config.xml at that time i move my app-config.xml to src folder but it didn't work, then i use file sperator while giving a path and it works, i.e. i have done the same thing in sqlmapconfig.xml file. so it's not working when we move it to src folder. please give any other solution

Comment: can you post the code for app-config.xml using file-separator,Probably we can cross check if both are same.

Comment: my app-config.xml is as below:  <bean id="sqlMapClient" class="org.springframework.orm.ibatis.SqlMapClientFactoryBean">
  <property name="configLocation"
   value="file:D:${file.separator}Projects${file.separator}pg${file.separator}LMeX${file.separator}source-files${file.separator}lmexserver${file.separator}lmexserver-mobile${file.separator}lmexserver-mobile-web${file.separator}src${file.separator}main${file.separator}webapp${file.separator}WEB-INF${file.separator}spring${file.separator}SqlMapConfig.xml" />
 </bean>

Comment: as you can see in above post,you have given the path that is under src,please give the path which is under src and try.it should work.!!!